Blaze Persistence Criteria Query: Order by Identifier Issue with Paginated Results
I'm working on a Spring Boot application using Blaze Persistence to construct a complex criteria query for fetching paginated results. However, I'm encountering an error that states: "The order by items of the query builder are not guaranteed to produce unique tuples! Consider also ordering by the entity identifier!"
Here are the details of my entities and the criteria query I'm using:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity {
@Id
private Long orderId;
private String orderCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrderAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrderAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "issue_type_id", nullable = false)
    private IssueType issueType;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class OrderAction {
    @Id
    private Long actionId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_location_id", nullable = false)
    private Location currentLocation;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "next_location_id", nullable = false)
    private Location nextLocation;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class OrderAttribute {
    @Id
    private Long attributeId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;
    
    private String key;
    private String value;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class IssueType {
    @Id
    private Long typeId;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String type;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Location {
    @Id
    private Integer locationId;
    private String locationCode;
    private String name;
    private Integer parentLocationId;
}

@Component
public class OrderRepositoryCustomImpl implements OrderRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    private final CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf;

    public OrderRepositoryCustomImpl(EntityManager em, CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf) {
        this.em = em;
        this.cbf = cbf;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<OrderListProjection> search(SearchRequest searchRequest, Pageable pageable) {
        CriteriaBuilder<Tuple> cb = cbf.create(em, Tuple.class)
                .from(OrderEntity.class, "o")
                .select("o.orderId", "orderId")
                .select("o.orderCode", "orderCode")
                .select("loc.locationId", "nextLocationId")
                .select("loc.name", "nextLocationName")
                .select("it.type", "issueType")
                .select("oa.value", "attributeValue")
                .select("loc.parentLocationId", "parentLocationId")
                .select("loc.name", "parentLocationName")
                .select("loc.locationCode", "locationCode")
                .innerJoin("o.issueType", "it")
                .leftJoinLateralOnEntitySubquery("o.actions", "topAction", "action")
                .orderByDesc("action.actionId")
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .end()
                .on("1").eqExpression("1")
                .end()
                .leftJoin("topAction.nextLocation", "loc")
                .leftJoinOnEntitySubquery("o", OrderAttribute.class, "oa")
                .end()
                .on("oa.orderEntity").eqExpression("o")
                .on("oa.key").eq("attributeKey").end();


        if (searchRequest.getIssueType() != null) {
            cb.where("it.type").eq(searchRequest.getIssueType());
        }
        if (searchRequest.getParentLocationId() != null) {
            cb.where("loc.parentLocationId").eq(searchRequest.getParentLocationId());
        }
        if (searchRequest.getAttributeValue() != null) {
            cb.where("oa.value").eq(searchRequest.getAttributeValue());
        }

        PaginatedCriteriaBuilder<Tuple> builder = cb.page((int) pageable.getOffset(), pageable.getPageSize());

        pageable.getSort().forEach(order -> {
            String property = order.getProperty();
            if (order.isAscending()) {
                builder.orderByAsc("o." + property);
            } else {
                builder.orderByDesc("o." + property);
            }
        });

        builder.orderByAsc("o.orderId");

        PagedList<Tuple> resultList = builder.withKeysetExtraction(true).getResultList();

        List<OrderListProjection> list = resultList.stream()
                .map(tuple -> new OrderListProjection(
                        tuple.get("orderId", Long.class),
                        tuple.get("orderCode", String.class),
                        tuple.get("nextLocationId", Integer.class),
                        tuple.get("nextLocationName", String.class),
                        tuple.get("issueType", String.class),
                        tuple.get("attributeValue", String.class),
                        tuple.get("parentLocationId", Integer.class),
                        tuple.get("parentLocationName", String.class),
                        tuple.get("locationCode", String.class)))
                .toList();

        return new PageImpl<>(list, pageable, resultList.getTotalSize());
    }
}

error: The order by items of the query builder are not guaranteed to produce unique tuples! Consider also ordering by the entity identifier!
I've tried adjusting the order by clause to include the entity identifier, but the issue persists.
pageable.getSort().forEach(order -> {
 String property = order.getProperty();
    if (order.isAscending()) {
        builder.orderByAsc("o." + property);
    } else {
        builder.orderByDesc("o." + property);
    }
});
    
builder.orderByAsc("o.orderId");
    

I've tried removing above piece of code, still the issue persists.
I expected the query to execute without errors and return unique tuples for pagination.
How can I resolve the issue of ensuring unique tuples when ordering by multiple fields in my Blaze Persistence criteria query? Any guidance on what I'm missing or how to adjust my query would be greatly appreciated.


You will have to use the pageBy method and tell Blaze-Persistence about the id attribute by which you want to paginate. Since your query is not fetching an entity directly, Blaze-Persistence can't figure this out by itself.
You are using a projection though, why not use Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views then? There is also a nice integration with Spring Data that takes care of all the pagination details. You just pass your Spring Data Pageable.

Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried using the pageBy method to specify the id attribute by which I want to paginate. However, I am still encountering the same error message. Tried both o.orderId and orderId.

I have also experimented with Entity-Views.
.leftJoinLateralOnEntitySubquery("o.actions", "topAction", action").orderByDesc("action.actionId").setMaxResults(1).end().on("1").eqExpression("1").end()
For above part of code, I was unable to use MappingSubquery for the whole object and then fill fields from the returned object efficiently. Attempting to write MappingSubquery for each field individually results in multiple subqueries for the same object, which I believe is not optimal.
Could you suggest any better alternatives for handling this scenario.

You can use secondary entity view roots for this purpose.
